# Как сделать решение примера и запись в файл?

Tags: python

Начнем по порядку.
У меня есть файл, в нем число 100 (без кавычек) ->
Я пишу код:

```
File = open("c://tmp/file.py", 'w')
Pre = File+9
File.write(str(pre))
File.close
```

Где File+9, 9 это число, которое нужно прибавить к числу в файле, и перезаписать файл с окончательным ответом (109).

Но в консоль потом пишется ошибка конкатенации, я не могу разобраться, помогите!

Comment: Один из вариантов: открываете файл в режиме чтения, читаете из него данные, преобразовываете в число, прибавляете 9, закрываете файл. Переоткрываете файл в режиме записи, записываете новое число, закрываете файл. Другой вариант - открывать в режиме чтения-записи, после чтения переместиться на начало файла и записать новое число.

Comment: Число нужно прибавить к числу в файле, а не к файлу!

Comment: Вам нужно прочитать содержимое файла, а вы его только открыли, и всё. Этого недостаточно.

Comment: хм... вы открыли файл...  сколько будет файл +9?  добавьте f = int(File.read()), а замете уже можно сложить f+9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подытожив все комментарии:

```
File = open("c://tmp/file.py", 'r')
str_number = File.read()
File.close()
number = int(str_number)+9
File = open("c://tmp/file.py", 'w')
File.write(str(number))
File.close()
```

Второй раз за день скидываю эту статью, надеюсь поможет разобраться с файлами - https://tproger.ru/articles/files-in-python/